# Need help understanding Authentication and Identity concepts in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authentication

I've read the Authentication section of the ASP.NET Core 2 documentation and I obviously got them to work but I'm still unclear on several terms/concepts in Authentication and Identity in ASP.NET Core 2.

Specifically:

What are ClaimsIdentity and ClaimsPrincipals, like what are the concepts behind them not just a one-liner about how they connect to each other or how to use them.

Also what are Authentication Schemes, Sign In Schemes and Challenge Schemes, in fact what exactly is meant by scheme here?

How exactly does cookie authentication work (like I understand how to make it work but I don't understand exactly what goes on behind the scenes and when?)

It would be beneficial if you could direct me to books/resources that take their time to explain the concepts behind the Authentication and Identity modules, especially local accounts.

I just feel that most of the documentation is about "do this and do that" without explaining overall concepts and I feel I would be a lot more comfortable using these things and knowing what and when to customize these things with that knowledge with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both are part of claims-based  authorization model known as the Identity Model and is part of the WCF , to get the full grasp of the concept you should go over if.